# How to change label colors programmatically in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I change the label color on my display programmatically, but that doesn't really change the color of the label in my simulator

this is my code :

This code works for iOS v13.3, but not for iOS v12.4

```
lblClockOut.text = "text"

lblClockOut.textColor = UIColor(named: "Green-9920")
```

is there any other way?

before that I say thank you :)

Comment: `// load from main bundle` 
is this Green-9920 available in bundle ?

Comment: getting color from bundle is main problem to ensure that try to set color like UIColor.red ... if this change the color ... then your color in bundle has wrong name or not working

Comment: thanks @jawadAli, set color with lblClockOut.textColor = UIColor.red also doesn't work in simulator version 12.4

Comment: which xcode version you are using ?

Comment: By the way Green-9920, it's in my bundle, and it works in simulator 13.3

Comment: Xcode Version 11.3

Comment: checkout this link ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580212/issues-with-named-colors-on-ios-11-with-xcode-11-beta

Comment: Have you tried updating UI on main thread like, DispatchQueue.main.async{ self.lblClockOut.textColor = UIColor(named: "Green-9920") }

Comment: @Ali when are you setting the label color? e.g. ViewDidLoad?

Comment: @kd02 I use if else, if status == nil, I will run the color exchange function as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried updating UI on main thread like,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{ self.lblClockOut.textColor = UIColor(named: "Green-9920") }
```

Answer (score -1):

In my projects I would apply colors like this:

```
extension UIColor {

    static let green_9920 = #colorLiteral(red: 0.0862745098, green: 0.8509803922, blue: 0.4470588235, alpha: 1)

}

// Usage example:

lblClockOut.textColor = .green_9920
```

I've never had issues with simulators so maybe this will work for you. Your code seems fine at first glance so not sure why its not working but you could try resetting the iOS 12 simulator and maybe its something to do with the referencing of your  custom color.